# Scp command between 2 servers with 2 different .pem keys

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, scp

I want to transfer a folder from server A to server B with scp and 2 different .pem keys.

Is this the best way to go about it and will this actually work.

```
scp -i ~/Documents/server1.pem -r root@server1.com:~/location/to/dir -i ~/Documents/server2.pem ~/location/to/copy/to
```

or do I have to input:

```
scp -i ~/Documents/server1.pem -r root@server1.com:~/location/to/dir -i ~/Documents/server2.pem root@server2.com:~/location/to/copy/to
```

I am just not sure with the second location if I need to input the host or just the location. 
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `~/location/to/copy/to` is a local path; you need the `root@server2.com:` prefix to indicate a remote destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a config file like `~/scp_config`:

```
Host src
    HostName server1.com
    User root
    CertificateFile %d/Documents/server1.pem

Host dest
    HostName server2.com
    User root
    CertificateFile %d/Documents/server2.pem
```

Then run

```
scp -3 -F ~/scp_config src:\~/location/to/dir dest:\~/location/to/copy/to
```

Comment: Explaining why did you use `-3` switch would be nice.

Comment: I did not know about `-3` until reading @xhienne's answer. Presumably, you need that if the local `scp` is establishing connections to the two remote servers, rather than `scp` asking `server1` to connect to `server2`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, does the scp_config have to be put in my local directory so that of the computer that I am transfering, not the A or B server. Kindest regards

Comment: It has to *somewhere* on your local machine, although you are free to put it anywhere since you are specifying the path directly with the `-F` option. My understanding is that *because* the information is then in a local file, not on either remote server, you need the `-3` option.

Comment: Hello again, I have just tried to implement this but I am getting an error. Permission denied (publickey).
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Does the `CertificateFile %d/` have to be replaced `~` or is that just the root directory

Comment: `CertificateFile` is the directive; `%d` is the `sshconfig` equivalent of `~` in shell.

Comment: `CertificateFile` directive didn't work for me. I had to use `IdentityFile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `scp` will only accept one `-i` option, so none of your commands will work.

Next, you are not using the `-3` option. That means that the transfer will occur directly between server1 and server2, without passing through your machine. In that case, that would be on server1 that server2's certificate needs to be stored.

One solution was already given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15648/). And if server1 can not connect directly to server2, see also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120673/) for the `-3` option.

Another solution is to use two `ssh` processes, each with its own `-i` option. Something like:

```
ssh -i ~/Documents/server1.pem root@server1.com 'tar cz -C ~/location/to/dir .' \
| ssh -i ~/Documents/server2.pem root@server2.com 'tar xz -C ~/location/to/copy/to'
```

Notes:

- this way, the files pass through your own machine, like `scp`'s `-3` option
- you may want to create the destination directory first (add an `mkdir -p` command before `tar x`)
- you may want to use `--no-same-owner` in the `tar x` command to have the files owned by root, and not by their original owner