# Why ssh connect by -i flag and not with -F flag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to make the ssh connection to amazon service by separate config file.

Also I need to transfer files from one server to another server and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017291/scp-command-between-2-servers-with-2-different-pem-keys)  advice to use separate config file.

It connect when I use it by

```
ssh -i ~/Desktop/ssh_keys/prod.pem ec2-user@***.***.***.***
```

But not when I use separate config:

```
ssh -F ~/Desktop/ssh_keys/scp_config prod
```

**scp_config**:

```
Host prod
    HostName ***.***.***.***
    User ec2-user
    CertificateFile ~/Desktop/ssh_keys/prod.pem
```

**debug info**:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/Desktop/ssh_keys/scp_config
debug1: /home/user/Desktop/ssh_keys/scp_config line 1: Applying options for prod
debug1: Connecting to ***.***.***.*** [***.***.***.***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: certificate file /home/user/Desktop/ssh_keys/prod.pem type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 174.129.126.138:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ****************
SHA256: ********************
debug1: Host '***.***.***.*** is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What's wrong with my settings?

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with my question? Can you write down your recommendations in comment?

Comment: this question seems be to more appropriate for https://superuser.com/. This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Molecular Man, what should I do with this question? Delete this question and post the copy in superuser.com?

Comment: I don't know. It's up to you. If you think this question will be usefull for someone else then it might be a good idea to repost this question at superuser as this question probably is going to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use IdentityFile parameter to specify your private key.

**IdentityFile**
             specifies a file from which the user's  RSA authentication
             identity is read.

scp_config:

```
Host prod
    HostName ***.***.***.***
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/Desktop/ssh_keys/prod.pem
```

> CertificateFile specifies a file from which the user's certificate is read.  A corresponding private
>                key must be provided separately in order to use this certificate either from an
>                IdentityFile directive or -i flag to ssh
>
> IdentityFile may also be used in conjunction with CertificateFile in order to provide any certificate also needed for authentication with the identity.